# Sending email thru Amazon SES with vb.net returns "Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream"

Tags: vb.net, amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses

I am using vb.net to send email thru Amazon SES. I am using .net framework 4.0. The code won't work on my development machine (Win XP SP3) but works flawlessly on Win2k8 R2 server.

I have seen many having the same issue on windows server, and fix it with this : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948963, but haven't found any fix yet for my XP machine.

I would appreciate some help with my issue. Detail of the exception follows :

Thank you for your help

```
 Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(String from, String recipients, String subject, String body)
       at SMSNotifier.Form2.SendWithSMTP(String username, String password, String host, Int32 port) in C:\Documents and Settings\rprosper.COOPERATIVA\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SMSNotifier\SMSNotifier\Form2.vb:line 17
  InnerException: System.IO.IOException
       Message=Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
```

Comment: May be your firewall or provider firewall close smtp connection?

Comment: No, pretty sure it's not the case. I know it has to see with SSL encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Someone is dropping the connection.

It could be Amazon if you're not authenticating properly or using the right port/address, or it could be your ISP, since many block outbound SMTP connections, however without seeing the code, it's pretty much impossible to be more specific.

On a more generic note, you can test your SES connection using openssl, which will give you a lot more information than your current error message.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html